# Xamarin.Forms.Labs - Checkboxes in ListView not working on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display a list of checkboxes (using control from Xamarin.Forms.Labs libriary) inside a Xamarin.Forms app. I followed [Xamarin.Forms.Labs wiki](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki) to initialize the app properly.

It works fine on Android, however when I try it on Windows Phone 8 emulator, the checkboxes don't change their state when clicked/tapped.

I have following XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Controls;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Labs"
                       x:Class="App4.CheckBoxPage">
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <controls:CheckBox DefaultText="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" FontSize="25" />
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

... and simple code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App4
{    
    public partial class CheckBoxPage : ContentPage
    {    
        public CheckBoxPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            listView.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).OfType<DayOfWeek>().Select(c => c.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class App
    {
        public static Page GetMainPage()
        {
            return new CheckBoxPage();            
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get the Checkboxes working?

Comment: Are you initializing Xamarin Forms Labs ? Do you have other renderers that work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, as it simply don't work on iOS and WP right now.
On Android you have to set the TextColor (else no text is showed).
But... the problems are knowed by the XLabs-team.

See also here: [XF-forum-thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/111091/#Comment_111091)

and here: [Issues-Page on XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues)

Hope this helps...